# The daily reputation list doesn't match the daily bars in the graphical reputation summary

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I recently noticed that the question/answer-level summary of reputation changes that you get when clicking the daily reputation bars doesn't match the correct day. Instead you get a list of the reputation changes during the previous day.

This screenshot makes this clear, and the list shown below belongs to the day to the left of the grey bar:

[image]

also, where the list is empty since it is showing reputation changes for Jun 6, and not the selected day:

[image]

I noticed this at BiologySE, but have the same problem on StackOverflow. I'm using Firefox 38.0.5 on windows 7, if this should make a difference.

Comment: I can't reproduce in Pale Moon 25.5.0 (a Firefox fork) on Win 8.1 on either SO or MSE. What time zone are you in?

Comment: I'm currently on GMT+2.

Comment: I'm in GMT-5, and my activity often straddles UTC midnight... still, it might be some sort of odd glitch with a local time issue.

Comment: Yes, it might be a timezone problem, but I've never encountered this issue previously (~last 1.5y), neither during mornings or afternoons. So something must have changed.

Comment: This question had not been asked before (the other one is a duplicate), and it doesn't have an answer, so I don't understand why it's closed.

Comment: It just got duped to the bug report that got more notice to make sure everything was unified. Doesn't mean you did anything wrong, it's just to make sure the bug tracking is efficient.